Trying to make the Flutter App Automation find element methods
I am using the existing format which used in project for Android App Automation. Now I have to create the same thing for Flutter App.
public static AppiumLocator findMobileLocatorElement(
      final String pageName,
      final String elementName,
      AppiumDriver driver,
      Object... dynamicLocatorValue) {
    return findMobileLocatorElement(
        pageName, elementName, driver, AppiumLocator::getElement, dynamicLocatorValue);
  }

  /**
   * Finds the page element.
   *
   * @param pageName page name tag in web locator file.
   * @param elementName name of element.
   * @return instance of weblocator class.
   */
  private static AppiumLocator findMobileLocatorElement(
      final String pageName,
      final String elementName,
      AppiumDriver webdriver,
      BiFunction<String, String, AppiumLocator> appiumLocatorProvider,
      Object... dynamicLocatorValue) {
    AppiumLocator appiumLocator;
    Map<String, String> locatorMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      locatorMap = WebLocatorFileTypeFactory.getInstance().getLocatorValue(pageName, elementName);
    } catch (JAXBException exception) {
      log.warn("Failed to read OR file for pagename {}", pageName, exception);
    }
    if (!locatorMap.isEmpty()) {
      for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : locatorMap.entrySet()) {
        if (0 == dynamicLocatorValue.length) {
          appiumLocator = appiumLocatorProvider.apply(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        } else {
          appiumLocator =
              appiumLocatorProvider.apply(
                  String.format(entry.getValue(), dynamicLocatorValue), entry.getKey());
        }
        try {
          webdriver.findElement(appiumLocator.getBy());
          return appiumLocator;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          log.info("Not able to find element: {} with locator : {}.", elementName, appiumLocator);
        }
      }
    } else {
      log.error(
          "NameOfElement or SectionName is given wrong in object repository file or PageName in Page Object"
              + " Class is wrong");
    }
    webdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    throw new NoSuchElementException(
        String.format(
            "no valid WebLocator found in object repository for page: %s and element: %s",
            pageName, elementName));
  }

I am creating the same format for Flutter App: but it is showing error when I am calling findMobileLocatorElement Method, what i did wrong while calling the below method?
public static FlutterLocator findMobileLocatorElement(
          final String pageName,
          final String elementName,
          AppiumDriver driver,
          Object... dynamicLocatorValue) {
    return findMobileLocatorElement(
            pageName, elementName, driver, FlutterLocator::getElement, dynamicLocatorValue);
  }


  private static FlutterLocator findMobileLocatorElement(
          final String pageName,
          final String elementName,
          AppiumDriver webdriver,
          BiFunction<String, String, FlutterLocator> appiumLocatorProvider,
          Object... dynamicLocatorValue) {
    FlutterLocator flutterLocator = null;
    Map<String, String> locatorMap = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      locatorMap = WebLocatorFileTypeFactory.getInstance().getLocatorValue(pageName, elementName);
    } catch (JAXBException exception) {
      log.warn("Failed to read OR file for pagename {}", pageName, exception);
    }
    if (!locatorMap.isEmpty()) {
      for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : locatorMap.entrySet()) {
        if (0 == dynamicLocatorValue.length) {
          flutterLocator = appiumLocatorProvider.apply(entry.getValue(), entry.getKey());
        } else {
          flutterLocator =
                  appiumLocatorProvider.apply(
                          String.format(entry.getValue(), dynamicLocatorValue), entry.getKey());
        }
        try {
          webdriver.findElement(flutterLocator.getBy());
          return flutterLocator;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          log.info("Not able to find element: {} with locator : {}.", elementName, flutterLocator);
        }
      }
    } else {
      log.error(
              "NameOfElement or SectionName is given wrong in object repository file or PageName in Page Object"
                      + " Class is wrong");
    }
    webdriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    throw new NoSuchElementException(
            String.format(
                    "no valid WebLocator found in object repository for page: %s and element: %s",
                    pageName, elementName));
  }

I want to call the method

My feedback is that you've made this WAY too complicated. You've got way too many fail points. .findMobileLocatorElement() should only have 1 parameter, a By locator. I would suggest you research the page object model to break up your locators and methods into discrete classes, one for each page/screen and that will get rid of a lot of the complexity you have in your code that isn't necessary.

It is a part of project i have to use the same structure

You need to edit your question and post the full error message as text, properly formatted.
